# Handling multiple artists in foobar2000

Tags: foobar2000

My music library consists of many collaborations between artists. At the moment it's displayed as "Artist 1 & Artist 2 - Album Name". But I want the same album to show up under both "Artist 1" and "Artist 2" rather than creating a whole new group for the 1 collaboration between them.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Write "Artist 1; Artist 2" to the artist tag. Foobar2000 supports multiple values for metadata fields.

Answer (score 2):

Foobar will automatically split up the field if it is formatted like `artist1 / artist2` (don't forget the spaces)

You can convert existing fields from another delimier like `&`, `,`, `;` to this. Simply go into the Properties of the Song -> rightclick on artist name -> split values

Comment: `,` isn't working for me but `;` is working ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Foobar considers multiple artists using the ";" (semicolon) separator between artist names without spaces

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).